# Getting driver files for a particular device

Tags: delphi, file, driver, enumerate

I would like to know how I can get all the driver files for a particular device just like the Device Manager does?

I have the following code:

```
procedure TdlgMain.Test(const DeviceIndex: Integer);
var
  PnPHandle: HDEVINFO;
  DevData: TSPDevInfoData;
  DeviceInterfaceData: TSPDeviceInterfaceData;
  FunctionClassDeviceData: PSPDeviceInterfaceDetailData;
  Success: LongBool;
  Devn: Integer;
  BytesReturned: DWORD;
  SerialGUID: TGUID;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@DevData, SizeOf(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
  DevData.cbSize := SizeOf(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

  ZeroMemory(@DeviceInterfaceData, SizeOf(TSPDeviceInterfaceData));
  DeviceInterfaceData.cbSize := SizeOf(TSPDeviceInterfaceData);

  if not SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hAllDevices,
    DeviceIndex, DevData) then Exit;

  SerialGUID := DevData.ClassGuid;

  PnPHandle := SetupDiGetClassDevs(@SerialGUID, nil, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT or DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
  if PnPHandle = Pointer(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    Exit;

  Devn := 0;
  repeat
    DeviceInterfaceData.cbSize := SizeOf(TSPDeviceInterfaceData);
    Success := SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(PnPHandle, nil, SerialGUID, Devn, DeviceInterfaceData);
    if Success then
    begin
      DevData.cbSize := SizeOf(DevData);
      BytesReturned := 0;
      // get size required for call
      SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(PnPHandle, @DeviceInterfaceData, nil, 0, BytesReturned, @DevData);
      if (BytesReturned <> 0) and (GetLastError = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) then
      begin
        // allocate buffer and initialize it for call
        FunctionClassDeviceData := AllocMem(BytesReturned);
        FunctionClassDeviceData.cbSize := SizeOf(TSPDeviceInterfaceDetailData);
        //FunctionClassDeviceData.cbSize := BytesReturned;
        if SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(PnPHandle, @DeviceInterfaceData,
          FunctionClassDeviceData, BytesReturned, BytesReturned, @DevData) then
        begin
          ShowMessage(FunctionClassDeviceData.DevicePath);
        end else
          RaiseLastOSError();
        FreeMem(FunctionClassDeviceData);
      end;
    end;
    Inc(Devn);
  until not Success;
  SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(PnPHandle);
```

But the `ShowMessage()` is either not called at all or returns `\`. How do I get the files properly?

I had a look at `devcon` from the WinDDK, but it does not return the files either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. There's no API to do it for you, you need to parse the INF files to achieve the result. Here's a quick-n-dirty solution for all of you, who are interested.

```
procedure TdlgMain.Test(const DeviceIndex: Integer);
var
  Paths: TStringList;
  I: Integer;

  function GetWinDir: string; inline;
  var
    dir: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
  begin
    GetWindowsDirectory(dir, MAX_PATH);
    Result := IncludeTrailingBackslash(StrPas(dir));
  end;

  function GetSpecialFolderPath(const folder: Integer): string; inline;
  const
    SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT = 0;
  var
    path: array [0 .. MAX_PATH] of Char;
  begin
    if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0, folder, 0, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, @path[0]))
    then
      Result := IncludeTrailingBackslash(path)
    else
      Result := '';
  end;

  function LocateInfFile(const F: String): String; inline;
  var
    T: String;
  begin
    Result := '';

    if (Pos(SysUtils.PathDelim, F) > 0) then
    begin
      Result := F;
      Exit;
    end;

    T := GetWinDir();
    if (FileExists(T + 'inf\' + F)) then
      Result := T + 'inf\' + F
    else if (FileExists(T + 'system32\' + F)) then
      Result := T + 'system32\' + F;
  end;

  procedure ReadSectionNoKeys(const AFile, ASection: String;
    const SL: TStringList);
  var
    TheFile: TStringList;
    Line: String;
    TrimEnd: Boolean;
    Idx, Tmp: Integer;
  begin
    TrimEnd := False;

    TheFile := TStringList.Create();
    try
      TheFile.LoadFromFile(AFile);
      Idx := TheFile.IndexOf('[' + ASection + ']');
      if (Idx <> -1) then
      begin
        Idx := Idx + 1;
        while True do
        begin
          Line := Trim(TheFile[Idx]);
          Inc(Idx);
          if (Pos(';', Line) = 1) then
            continue;

          if (Pos('[', Line) > 0) then
            Break;

          Tmp := Pos(',', Line);
          if (Tmp > 0) then
            TrimEnd := True
          else
          begin
            Tmp := PosEx(';', Line, 3);
            if (Tmp > 0) then
              TrimEnd := True;
          end;

          if (Line <> '') then
          begin
            if (TrimEnd) then
            begin
              Line := Trim(Copy(Line, 1, Tmp - 1));
              TrimEnd := False;
            end;

            SL.Add(Line);
          end;

          if (Idx = (TheFile.Count - 1)) then
            Break;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      TheFile.Free();
    end;
  end;

  function IniReadStr(const Ini: TIniFile; const S, L, D: String): String;
  var
    T: Integer;
  begin
    Result := Ini.ReadString(S, L, D);

    T := Pos(';', Result);
    if (T > 0) then
      Result := Trim(Copy(Result, 1, T - 1));
  end;

  procedure ParseInfFile(const InfFile, SectionName: String);
  var
    I: TIniFile;
    SL, FilesList: TStringList;
    X, Y, Tmp: Integer;
    Pth, S, S1: String;
  begin
    I := TIniFile.Create(InfFile);
    try
      if (SectionName <> '') and (I.SectionExists(SectionName)) then
      begin
        // Check if the section has a value called "CopyFiles".
        if (I.ValueExists(SectionName, 'CopyFiles')) then
        begin
          // It has. Read it to a string and separate by commas.
          SL := TStringList.Create();
          try
            SL.CommaText := IniReadStr(I, SectionName, 'CopyFiles', '');

            // Now, every line of the string list is a section name. Check
            // the destination directory of each.
            if (I.SectionExists('DestinationDirs')) then
              for X := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
              begin
                S := IniReadStr(I, 'DestinationDirs', SL[X], '');
                if (S = '') then
                  S := IniReadStr(I, 'DestinationDirs', 'DefaultDestDir', '');

                if (S <> '') then
                begin
                  // Split the path by comma, if any.
                  Tmp := Pos(',', S);
                  S1 := '';
                  if (Tmp > 0) then
                  begin
                    S1 := Trim(Copy(S, Tmp + 1, Length(S)));
                    S := Trim(Copy(S, 1, Tmp - 1));
                  end;

                  // Convert the numeric value of S to a proper directory.
                  Pth := '';
                  if (S = '10') then
                    Pth := GetWinDir();
                  if (S = '11') then
                    Pth := GetWinDir() + 'system32\';
                  if (S = '12') then
                    Pth := GetWinDir() + 'system32\drivers\';
                  if (S = '50') then
                    Pth := GetWinDir() + 'system\';
                  if (S = '30') then
                    Pth := ExtractFileDrive(GetWinDir());
                  if (StrToInt(S) >= 16384) then
                    Pth := GetSpecialFolderPath(StrToInt(S));

                  if (S1 <> '') then
                    Pth := IncludeTrailingBackslash(Pth + S1);

                  // If we got the path, read the files.
                  if (Pth <> '') then
                  begin
                    FilesList := TStringList.Create();
                    try
                      ReadSectionNoKeys(InfFile, SL[X], FilesList);
                      for Y := 0 to FilesList.Count - 1 do
                        if (Paths.IndexOf(Pth + FilesList[Y]) = -1) then
                          Paths.Add(Pth + FilesList[Y]);
                    finally
                      FilesList.Free();
                    end;
                  end;
                end;
              end;
          finally
            SL.Free();
          end;
        end;

        // Check if there're "Include" and "Needs" values.
        if ((I.ValueExists(SectionName, 'Include')) and
          (I.ValueExists(SectionName, 'Needs'))) then
        begin
          // Split both by comma.
          SL := TStringList.Create();
          FilesList := TStringList.Create();
          try
            SL.CommaText := IniReadStr(I, SectionName, 'Include', '');
            FilesList.CommaText := IniReadStr(I, SectionName, 'Needs', '');
            if (SL.Text <> '') and (FilesList.Text <> '') then
              for X := 0 to SL.Count - 1 do
                for Y := 0 to FilesList.Count - 1 do
                  ParseInfFile(LocateInfFile(SL[X]), FilesList[Y]);
          finally
            FilesList.Free();
            SL.Free();
          end;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      I.Free();
    end;
  end;

begin
  Paths := TStringList.Create();
  try
    ParseInfFile(LocateInfFile(DeviceHelper.InfName), DeviceHelper.InfSection);
    Paths.Sort();

    ListView_InsertGroup(lvAdvancedInfo.Handle, 'Driver Files', 2);
    for I := 0 to Paths.Count - 1 do
      ListView_AddItemsInGroup(lvAdvancedInfo, '', Paths[I], 2);
  finally
    Paths.Free();
  end;
end;
```